# What is the payload for register an iOS device?

Tags: c#, ios, maui, azure-notificationhub

In my `.NET8 MAUI` i Want to add the push notification via Azure Notification Hub. Reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/create-overwrite-installation?view=rest-notificationhubs-2023-09-01), I wrote this code to create an installation in the hub:

```cs
[Export("application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:")]
public async void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
{
    string token = deviceToken.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None)

    var deviceInstallation = new
    {
        InstallationId = token,
        Platform = "apns"
    };

    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-01");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization",
      CreateToken($"https://languageinuse.servicebus.windows.net",
          "DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature", Constants.PushNotificationSecret));

    var r = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync($"https://languageinuse.servicebus.windows.net/" +
            $"app/installations/{deviceInstallation.InstallationId}?api-version=2015-01",
                                deviceInstallation);
}
```

The result is a `Bad request and this is the result

```json
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler+NSUrlSessionDataTaskStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
  trackingid: 979df88e-a15e-4215-8f76-d77c9d23e0b3
  x-ms-correlation-request-id: d1ca2a1e-5b1a-499c-86cf-f9f3f61bb6f1
  Server: Kestrel
  Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2024 23:43:20 GMT
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
  trackingid: 979df88e-a15e-4215-8f76-d77c9d23e0b3
  Content-Type: application/xml
  x-ms-correlation-request-id: d1ca2a1e-5b1a-499c-86cf-f9f3f61bb6f1
}}
```

I don't understand where the problem is. Is the `PushChannel` required in the `deviceInstallation`? If yes, how can I get one? Is the `token` correct in this request?